# Task Was Canceled

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-web-api, model-view-controller, controller

I am trying to download PDF from the database by API call.. 
All PDF are getting downloaded but only for one row I am getting task was canceled exception

```
public async System.Threading.Tasks.Task<ActionResult> Record(string empNo)
{
    using (var client = new HttpClient())
    {

        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/pdf"));
        var response = client.GetAsync("URL?empNo=" + empNo).Result;

        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            var files = Directory.GetFiles(Server.MapPath(@"~/EmpPDF/"));
            foreach (var file in files)
            {
                try
                {
                    System.IO.File.Delete(file);
                }
                catch
                { }
            }
            var bytes = await response.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync();


            using (Stream writer = System.IO.File.Create(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(@"~EmpPDF/" + empNo + ".pdf")))
            {
                writer.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
                writer.Flush();
                responsePDFPath = @"/EmpPDF/" + empNo + ".pdf"; //+ response.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName;
            }

            ViewBag.PathToPdf = responsePDFPath;
            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

I am getting Task was cancelled exception for this code.

Comment: Deadlock because of mixing of blocking calls (`.Result`) and async code.

Comment: You really need to format your code, apparently there is a `}` missing.

Comment: You can skip those things.. Anyways I am getting perfect output.. Just only for one record I am getting an exception

Comment: How big is the file you are downloading? How long is your HttpClient timeout set to? If the file to download takes longer than your timeout setting, it will cause a TaskCancelledException

Answer (score 0):

Deadlock because of mixing of blocking calls (`.Result`) and `async-await` code.

```
 var response = client.GetAsync("URL?empNo=" + empNo).Result;
```

That line should be awaited as well

```
 var response = await client.GetAsync("URL?empNo=" + empNo);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try making sure to dispose the response object:

```
using(var response = await client.GetAsync("URL?empNo=" + empNo))
{
    // Rest of function
}
```

Leaving too many HttpResponseMessage objects un-disposed can tie up network resources, meaning that later requests will block waiting for one of those resources (which will never get freed, because there is no memory pressure to trigger a GC) and eventually time out.

I've had tons of projects that experience this very same deadlock. It's very important to dispose things that are IDiposable as soon as possible, *especially* HttpResponseMessage objects.

Comment: At this point I don't think there is much anyone can do to help with the info you've provided. It sounds like it's something outside this code... what people have suggested should have solved the problem. Try using something like Fiddler to see if the network requests are doing what you expect.